# Gstreamer can't negotiate v4l2src properly on Raspberry (Banana PI M2+)

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, banana-pi

I have an issue with v4l2 not reading the camera feed correctly. Or more probably gstreamer not initiating the v4l2 ctl correctly.

Infra:

Banana Pi M2+
[OV5640 Camera](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/BPR-5MP-Cam-ra-OV5640-Auto-zoom-avec-objectif-grand-angle-pour-Orange-Pi-PC-Pi/32869355445.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3a6c6c37d3OQnk)

```
modprobe ov5640
modprobe vfe_v4l2
```

My problem: 
Camera works fine with motion but I can't get it to work with gstreamer.

This is my manually compiled gstreamer:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! "image/jpeg,width=160,height=120,framerate=30/1" ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.2 port=5001
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3064): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.003571242
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...






ben@bananapim2plus:~/src/gst-plugins-good/tests/examples/v4l2$ ./v4l2src-renegotiate
Setting resolution to '320x240'
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:src: Device '/dev/video0' failed during initialization
Additional debug info:
gstv4l2object.c(3785): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:src:
Call to S_FMT failed for YUYV @ 320x240: Operation not permitted
ben@bananapim2plus:~/src/gst-plugins-good/tests/examples/v4l2$ ./camctrl
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:camera/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Device '/dev/video0' failed during initialization
Additional debug info:
gstv4l2object.c(3785): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstPipeline:camera/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
Call to S_FMT failed for YUYV @ 640x480: Operation not permitted
```

I can hear the camera "click"

Comment: Does `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` list the format you are trying to set? You need to set one that is supported by the camera.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch: Let's try with format index UYVY which is supported according to output of your command
`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! video/x-raw, format=UYVY , framerate=10/1, width=1280, height=720 ! filesink location=raw.yuv`
Launches, I let it run for a few minutes, CTRL-C -> filesize is 0 bytes

Comment: As Florian mentioned, seems like your camera does not allow you to capture in the format or resolution you want to set. Try capturing in the raw RGB format.

Comment: @vk_gst Here are my formats: https://pastebin.com/rGERQ9Ns
I tried to combine some with video/x-raw-yuv or video/x-raw-rgb without success

Comment: Using cap-v4l2 (from avafinger) I could determine and take snapshots up to 2592x1936 pixels. Used pixel format is: 1: [0x32315559] 'YU12' (planar YUV 420)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I managed to have it working!

```
video/x-raw,format=I420
```

Viewer side (Windows):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5001 caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)MP4V-ES\,\ profile-level-id\=\(string\)1\,\ config\=\(string\)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800cd3204709443000001b24c61766335362e312e30\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2873740600\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)391825150\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)2980" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! avdec_mpeg4 ! autovideosink
```

Camera side (Banana):

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=800,height=600,framerate=15/1 ! avenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay config-interval=3 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.2 port=5001
```